# How to open a new tab based on data taken from a FORM in "popup.html"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

I want to create a chrome extension which takes input from a "form" in popup.html and uses popup.js to open the website selected in a new tab.

## **manifest.json**

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Question Searcher",
  "description": "This extension displays the problem from popular online judges like UVA, SPOJ, Topcoder and Codeforces on serching the keyword. It also searches for a list of problems based on problem type.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

## **popup.html**

:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src = "popup.js" > </script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "theme.css" >
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1> Search </h1>
    <form name = "input">
    <p>
    Judge:
    <select name = "judge">
    <option value = "uva" selected> UVA </option>
    <option value = "spoj" > SPOJ </option>
    <option value = "tc" > Topcoder </option>
    <option value = "tcat" > Topcoder Category  </option>
    <option value = "cf" > Codeforces Category </option>
    </select>
    <input type = "text" name = "keyword"<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="return validate_register()">Go!</button> 
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

## **popup.js**

```
function validate_register()
{
    alert("beep");
    var str=document.forms["input"]["keyword"].value;
    //alert(str);
    switch(document.forms["input"]["judge"].value)
    {
        case "uva":
            return chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.uva.onlinejudge.org/external/'+str.substring(0,str.length-2)+'/'+str+'.html'});
        break;
        case "spoj":
            return chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.spoj.pl/problems/'+str.toUpperCase()+'/'});
        break;
        case "tc":
            return chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive&class='+str});
        break;
        case "tcat":
            return chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive&cat='+str});
        break;
        case "cf":
            return chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.codeforces.com/problemset/tags/'+str});
        break;
    }

}
```

This code is not working. I think the problem might be in the JS file, in chrome.tabs.create but i am not able to figure it out. Could someone point to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about Content Security Policy. When you're using manifest v2 for your chrome extension it doesn't allow to execute inline JavaScript in HTML code. (You can inspect popup with DevTools by right clicking on BrowserAction icon).

So that's why your `onclick` attribute isn't working. To fix this, you'll need to remove this attribute from HTML, and add code like this inside `popup.js`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validate_register();
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. :)